# How to save a pandas dataframe to an existing Excel sheet updating the entire sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Laura', 'Colin', 'David'],
        'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
        'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Berlin']}

# Creating DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to export this dataframe to the existing Excel file (.xlsx) 'Data.xlsx' to sheet 'Sheet1'. The dataframe should start from the cell 'A1'. If there is existing data on the sheet, I want to update the entire sheet. I tried the code below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_path = 'Data.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(file_path)

ws = wb['Sheet1']

ws['A1'] = df 

wb.save(file_path)
```

However, the following error occurs:

```
[4 rows x 3 columns] to Excel
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please read the library documentation first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use built in `to_excel()` with `'openpyxl'` engine? use `pd.ExcelWriter` to keep the existing sheets

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: There are other sheets in the file that I need to keep unchanged

Comment: @Andrei updated my answer.

Comment: But how to specify sheet name?

Comment: @Andrei you have `sheet_name` parameter with `'Sheet1'` as default.

Comment: That worked, thanks